# Getting npm start error while creating a react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I've created a react app, but I am struggling with a problem which it is caused in `npm start`. The error pops up whenever I use the command `react-scripts start` on my windows 7 32 bit OS.

(NOTE: I used ***npx create-react-app my-react*** to creatr the app)

Here is the error :

````
> my-react@0.1.0 start D:\WEB DEVELOPMENT\MyReact\my-react
> react-scripts start

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628
  throw e;
  ^

Error: No valid exports main found for 'D:\WEB DEVELOPMENT\MyReact\my-react\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\node_modules\postcss'
←[90m    at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:9)←[39m
←[90m    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:502:14)←[39m
←[90m    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:22)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:855:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\WEB DEVELOPMENT\MyReact\my-react\node_modules\←[4mpostcss-safe-parser←[24m\lib\safe-parse.js:1:17)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:30)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-react@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-react@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\ALL~FILE\APPS\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-20T16_33_30_649Z-debug.log ```
````

Comment: Can you share your project files (js,html,css)?

Comment: what's your node version?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. Delete `node_modules` folder
2. Delete the `package-lock.json` file which is at the root of your repository
3. Run these commands: `npm install` and then `npm start`

Explanation: It looks like some packages were installed incorrectly. These instructions will uninstall the various packages your react app needs to run propertly, and install them again.

Comment: You might try to check if you have the latest version of node.js installed

Comment: I have 13.4 version of nodejs. As Windows 7 no longer support the newest versions 